# How does .apply work when new a function which includes it?

Tags: javascript

As i know,key word `new` would create an object includes attributes defined in the function by using `this`.But i have no idea how `apply` chained other function to the function using `apply`.And the created object has attributes in these functions.Can anyone figure out what happened in the code?THX.

```
function foo() { this.a = 2; };
function bar() { this.b = 3; foo.apply(this); };
new bar();// {b: 3, a: 2}
```

Finally,i've got what it works by running these code.`this` was transferred to `bar` by `.apply()`.But it was still indicated to `foo`.So `this.b = 3` in `bar` is same as `this.a = 2` in `foo`.They share same context;(But it won't work like `prototype`,`prototype` should be another matter)

```
Function.prototype.ha = function () { console.log(this.prototype); console.log(this); }; 
function foo() { bar.apply(this); }; 
foo.prototype.baka = 233; 
function bar() { this.b = 23;console.log(this); };bar.prototype.maybe = 2333;
var test = new foo();// {b: 23}
test.baka;// 233
test.b;// 23
test.maybe;// undefined
```

Comment: [`Function.prototype.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

Comment: Are you asking how `.apply()` works specifically when used from within a function called with `new`, or just how `.apply()` works in general? (Actually there is no difference.)

Comment: `foo.apply(this)` will call the function `foo()` and set it's context to `this`. Note that `this` inside `bar()` when called with `new` will refer to the newly created instance. Then assigning `a` on `this` will indirectly add property `a` on this newly created instance.

Comment: They have nothig to do with each other.

Comment: @nnnnnn The first one, the `new` key word with `.apply()` makes me puzzled....0 0.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah that is a great question. The golden rule for *this* is that 80% of the time this = whatever is on the left side of the period.  Most of the other times it is scoped to whatever is calling the function.

*this* in foo would be equal to the function itself when it is invoked. 
*this* in bar would be equal to the function itself when it is invoked.
When declared inside of foo this.a = 2;
When declared inside of bar this.b = 3;

When you call new bar() on line 3 you are invoking the bar function.  You set its *this* binding to the function invocation or where it was called. When you invoke bar, foo is given the .apply method and then passed this.  You would think the .apply() would return undefined because there is no *this.a* property inside of the bar function.  However, because you are using apply within foo, you apply or carry over its *this* context as if it were invoked inside of the bar function.

So when you make the call on line 3.  You are given an object which returns { a: 3, b:2 }

Comment: *“this in foo would be equal to the function itself. this in bar would be equal to the function itself.”* That doesn’t sound right.